# Origin of "sitting there like Lord Fermoy"

Tags: phrase-origin

What is the origin of *sitting there like Lord Fermoy*? This had been a stock phrase in our family.

Comment: This question is the only hit when you Google “sitting there like Lord Fermoy”. It may be a stock phrase in your family, but it’s certainly not an established idiom. It was probably made up by someone in your family, in which case there’s no way of knowing what it was originally a reference to without finding the person who coined it and asking them.

Comment: There have been [six Barons Fermoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Fermoy) so far, so it may be possible to guess at which is referred to and why, if it's known when the phrase originated -- even despite its limited usage.

Comment: You're sure it's Fermoy and not a mishearing of [Fauntleroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Lord_Fauntleroy)?

Comment: " What does "sitting there like Lord Fermoy" mean?

Comment: If this is familect (as I suspect it is)  the origin is with your family.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's _not_ a phrase. Also, we don't know what it means, because the OP just assumed that we did.